# The designer could not be shown in VS2010 express

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have following class structure:

```
public partial class SickForm<T> : MyForm where T : class {}

public class MyForm : Form, ExternalAssemblyNamespace.ISomething {}
```

After opening `MyForm` in designer, everything loads properly. But after opening `SickForm` in designer, I'm facing this error:

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.  The designer inspected the following classes in the file:
>
> SickForm --- The base class 'MyForm' could not be loaded.  Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

How to fix this ? This problem occurs while I'm using VS2010 express. In VS2008 express it works ok.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution?

Comment: Well, what's special about MyForm?  Is it located in another assembly?  Does it have a default constructor?

Comment: Fresh rebuild doesn't help. It's the same assembly. There are 2 constructors in MyForm - the one of them is default and protected.

Comment: The `ISomething` interface is defined in separate assembly, if it is any clue. Without this inheritance works ok, but I need it anyway.

Comment: You also can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16089790/908336 It worked for me and is a very simple workaround compared to copying to `IDE\PublicAssemblies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/3398a2da-a524-4c41-b762-8917d5c80b3d) (can someone explain me, why I had to do it and how to resolve this issue in any better way ?)

For some reason, after I copied my external assembly which contains infamous `ISomething` declaration to `...\IDE\PublicAssemblies` directory, VS2010 started properly rendering form designer after restart.